# OptaPlanner sounds to stop at a local optimal

Tags: java, spring-boot, optaplanner

I am running an OptaPlanner service which schedules meetings. I have two @PlanningVariables which are meeting time and participants. I define the constraints as no overlap meetings, meeting orders pariticipant availabilies and etc as hard constraints. I define the load balancing among participants as medium constraints. However, the OptaPlanner would stop at some local optimal even violating hard constraints. And my input is very simple. Besides, I only have one phase. Not sure whether having multiple phases could help on it.

E.g, I have three days to assign the meetings. And obviously, on the second day, there is a solution that no constraints will be violated. However, it will stop on the first day and keep assigning different participants(There is one hard constraint violated on pariticipant availabilies) and not move meeting time to next day.
Do you have any suggestions on this issue and how could I improve on it?

I have tried LateAcceptance and tabuSearch algorithm, but both stops on the first day. I tried 10s - 60s, and it reaches the state very early ~3s and keeps assigning different participants.
I have also tried increasing weight on certain constraints, but still stopped at local optima.

I do delete the input of the first day, it then could find the best solution which is on the second day.

My current solver config:

```
<constructionHeuristic>    <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT</constructionHeuristicType> </constructionHeuristic>
<localSearch>
    <acceptor>
        <acceptorType>LATE_ACCEPTANCE</acceptorType>
    </acceptor> </localSearch>
</localSearch>
```

Comment: You might need to look into custom moves (see docs) to escape the local optima more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks @Geoffrey De Smet! I may find the root cause. It sounds during the first phase of constrution heuristics, some of the planningentity will have 0 constraints violated and then optaplanner fix it and move other planningentity according to constraints. However, the root cause is in construction heuristics, any suggestion apart from this wiki to fix it?
https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#scoreTrap

Comment: Besides, is it possible to apply custom moves in some specific conditions? I am afraid my custom moves would break the solver default move logic.